# disable button until value is selected ---select---doesnt appear

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, disabled-control, javascript

SO far everything working ok, button is disabled until value is selected from the drop down list,
However I want ---select--- to be the first option on the drop down list, but this is not happening...any ideas as to why?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSubContractors" runat="server" 
    AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="Company_Name" DataValueField="id" 
    onchange='selectChanged(this);'>
    <asp:ListItem Text="---Select---" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">

   function selectChanged(e) {
    document.getElementById("<%= addNewSubContractor.ClientID %>").disabled 
      = (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value == "0") ? "disabled" : "";
                          }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="addNewSubContractor" Text="Add Sub Contractor" 
    OnClick="UploadSubContractor" runat="server" disabled='disabled' />
```

Comment: I don't know about asp, but in HTML, there's the 'selected'-tag, which makes the corresponding entry the 'selected' one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing the manually added items first followed by the data bound items is the default behavior of the drop down list, so `---Select---` *should* in theory be the first item.

I suspect there is some logic elsewhere(can be javascript or code behind) which sets the selected item to something else i.e:

`DropDownListSubContractors.SelectedIndex = 1;`

Have a good look through your code and make sure the selected item is not being re-set anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Have you got append databound item set to true, this checks to see if there are any items in the collection, and adds them first before binding?